# Trying to create a new DataFrame from a slice of an old one and using another row as new columns values results in all NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe

To elaborate on the title, I have a DataFrame where one row contains the values that I want to set as new columns with subsequent rows forming the new rows to the DataFrame.

For example, I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| - | - | - |
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |
| g | h | i |
| k | l | m |
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
| d | e | f |
| - | - | - |
| g | h | i |
| k | l | m |
```

I've tried doing this via `pd.DataFrame(old_df.iloc[2:, :], columns=old_df.iloc[1, :].values)` but this results in the columns being correct but all row values being `NaN`.

```
>>> old_df = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['k', 'l', 'm']]
>>> old_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df, columns=[1, 2, 3])
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df.iloc[2:, :], columns=old_df.iloc[1, :].values)
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also convert the `old_df.iloc[2:, :]` to numpy array to remove the dataframe's column header

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(old_df.iloc[2:].values, columns=old_df.iloc[1].values)
```

```
$ print(new_df)

   d  e  f
0  g  h  i
1  k  l  m
```